# List of nested AJAX calls and $.when.apply - deferred promises not working right

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

I'm trying to make a triple nested series of AJAX calls; the basic structure is below (I've omitted fail calls).

It's working up to the second level with the eventCalls. The final `when.apply.done` only triggers after every single call to `event.eventUsers.href` has finished, as expected. But the third ajax call, the one inside the done of the `event.eventUser.href` call that retrieves user information, executes after the `console.log` in the when block. I'm sure I'm just not understanding the deferred/promises concept completely enough, could anyone clear this up? Thanks!

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET'
  url: '/api/events'
}).done(function(events, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  var eventCalls = [];
  $.each(events.items, function(index, event) {
    eventCalls.push(
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: event.eventUsers.href // Assoc objects for EventUser
        data: 'type=host' // Only one eventUser is returned
      }).done(function(eventUsers, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // Getting the eventUser's user information
        $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: eventUsers.items[0].user.href
        }).done(function(user, textStatus, jqXHR) {
          event.host = user;
        })
      })
    )
  })
  $.when.apply($, eventCalls).done(function() {
    console.log(events);
  })
})
```

Comment: Use `then` instead of `done`, and **always `return` a promise** from asynchronous functions! A promise doesn't can't know what happens in its callbacks, and doesn't wait with anything about that.

Comment: @Bergi Can you explain more? Should I use `then` everywhere? What do I return exactly in the `then` callback? Should I be returning the third ajax call?

Comment: No (sorry, maybe later), yes, any promise (even if made from `then`) or value, yes

Comment: @Bergi Thank you! I changed it from done to when and returned the ajax call and it's working. I'm still pretty unclear on the difference so I'm going to read up on that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here's the whole thing simplified by using :

- `$.get()` in place of `$.ajax()`
- `$.map()` to create the array of promises

and corrected with :

- `.then()` in place of `.done()` all through
- appropriate returns from the .then callbacks.

```
$.get('/api/events').then(function(events) {
    var queryString = 'type=host';//defined outside the $.map() loop for efficiency.
    var promises = $.map(events.items, function(item) {//$.map() loops through events.items and returns an array
        return $.get(item.eventUsers.href, queryString).then(function(eventUsers) {//note `return` 
            return $.get(eventUsers.items[0].user.href).then(function(user) {//note `return` 
                item.host = user;
                return item;//this return determines the value with which the final promise is resolved.
            });
        });
    });
    //at this point, `promises` is an array of promises each of which will be resolved when its `item.host` has been set
    $.when.apply(null, promises).then(function() {
        console.dir(events);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As you've been instructed by Bergi the solution is to replace `done` with `then` inside the nested AJAX call and to `return` the value.

The difference between `done` and `then` is that `done` adds a handler and returns *the same promise* while `then` adds a handler and returns *a new promise that resolves when what you return from the `then` resolves*.

```
eventCalls.push(
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: event.eventUsers.href,
    data: 'type=host' 
  }).then(function(eventUsers) { // `then` chaines promises
    return $.ajax({ // Promises chain with return values
      type: 'GET',
      url: eventUsers.items[0].user.href
    }).then(function(user, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      event.host = user; // synchronous so no big deal done would work
    }).then(function(){ return event; }); // resolve with event to show
  })
)
```

As a tip - you can use `.map` instead of `.each`.